# Is there an Ansible Playbook for provisioning an OS using ESX/i?

Tags: centos, vmware, redhat, ansible

Is their a way to provision an OS(Centos/Redhat) when using a licensed VMware vSphere server (with ESX/i) using ansible?

Comment: What does provision mean to you?

Comment: Also, vmware is a broad statement.. do you have vsphere of some kind? If so what version, is it workstation, fusion, vcloud director? You really need more details to get an accurate solution here.

Comment: Provision- deploy a OS using ansible template(will specify .iso, HDD,RAM)
we are using- VMware ESXi 5.5.0

Comment: Are you using a licensed version of ESXi or the free one?

Comment: @MichaelRice licensed only.. we dont have vcenter license

Answer (score 3):

The [vsphere_guest](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vsphere_guest_module.html) module will allow you to provision a guest VM through Ansible. If you want to do everything automatically via Ansible then you probably want to have the guest launch a [kickstart](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/ch-kickstart2.html) to automate the install of linux onto the VM, and once that's complete then you can use Ansible to perform any customizations to the environment that you desire.

Comment: In vsphere_guest module we need to provide vcenter_hostname, i dont have a vcenter

Comment: Based on your comment above: As long as your ESX/i is licensed you can use its host name in place of the vCenter hostname. The API is *mostly* the same. If the library is written correctly it should *just work* when using the ESX/i server.

Answer (score 1):

Official  VMware python bindings https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi. Ansible uses pysphere. I thought that you can develop ansible module:

> Ansible modules are reusable units of magic that can be used by the
>   Ansible API, or by the ansible or ansible-playbook programs.  The
>   directory ”./library”, alongside your top level playbooks, is also
>   automatically added as a search directory.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_modules.html#tutorial

Or take unofficial ansible module build on pyvmomi: 
 - https://github.com/ViaSat/ansible-vsphere

But as I see here: https://github.com/sijis/pyvmomi-examples/blob/master/create-vm.py you need vCenter.

There are vagrant plugins but I don't think that you can do provision on ESXi without vCenter.